# Getting current state in ngrx

Tags: rxjs, observable, ngrx, subject-observer

[Here](https://github.com/ngrx/store/blob/6a588ad755cc6511368a084b1bac94b260d24ed1/README.md#getstate-getvalue-and-value) is the solution for getting the current state in ngrx. The example is simple - you just use `take(1)`. But in rxjs documentation for `take` it says:

> Returns a specified number of contiguous elements from the start of an
>   observable sequence

How come taking the first value gets the current state (i.e. the last value)?

Also I'm having trouble mocking this behavior in unit tests using `Subject`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ngrx-store is a `ReplaySubject` of `length=1`, this means only 1(the latest) value is cached and replayed on subscribe - so `take(1)` will resolve to the latest value.